# extract values from HTML based on previous label

Tags: html, xpath

From this code :

```
<div class="">
                       <p class="text-muted">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> 19 nov 2022                             t/m 19 nov 2022                    </p>
                    <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><label class="pre">Type activiteit:</label></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"><label class="post">Kampioenschaps clubmatches</label></div><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Type activiteit field is required." id="page_ActivityType" name="page.ActivityType" type="hidden" value="ChampionshipClubmatches" data-np-invisible="1" data-np-checked="1"></div>
                    <p class="intro-text"></p>
                    <h3>Locatie</h3>
                    <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><label class="pre">Adres:</label></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"><label class="post">Dogcenter</label></div><input id="page_Adres" name="page.Adres" type="hidden" value="Dogcenter" data-np-invisible="1" data-np-checked="1"></div>
                    <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><label class="pre">Postcode:</label></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"><label class="post">Jan Stuversdreef 4</label></div><input id="page_Zipcode" name="page.Zipcode" type="hidden" value="Jan Stuversdreef 4" data-np-invisible="1" data-np-checked="1"></div>
                    <div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><label class="pre">Plaats:</label></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"><label class="post">5315 NZ Kerkwijk</label></div><input id="page_City" name="page.City" type="hidden" value="5315 NZ Kerkwijk" data-np-invisible="1" data-np-checked="1"></div>

                        <h3>Informatie</h3>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><label class="pre">Inschrijven vanaf:</label></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"><label class="post">1 apr 2022</label></div><input data-val="true" data-val-date="Het veld Inschrijven vanaf dient een datum te zijn." id="page_SignupDateFrom" name="page.SignupDateFrom" type="hidden" value="1-4-2022 00:00:00" data-np-invisible="1" data-np-checked="1"></div><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><label class="pre">Inschrijven tot:</label></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"><label class="post">1 okt 2022</label></div><input data-val="true" data-val-date="Het veld Inschrijven tot dient een datum te zijn." id="page_SignupDateTo" name="page.SignupDateTo" type="hidden" value="1-10-2022 00:00:00" data-np-invisible="1" data-np-checked="1"></div>
                        <h3>Organisatie</h3>
<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"><label class="pre">Website:</label></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"><label class="post"><a href="http://www.test.com/">http://www.test.com/</a></label></div><input id="page_OrganisationWebSite" name="page.OrganisationWebSite" type="hidden" value="http://www.test.com/" data-np-invisible="1" data-np-checked="1"></div>                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                    <label class="pre" for="page_OrganisationEmail">Email</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                                    <label class="post"><a href="mailto:jill@ascn.nl">email@test.com</a></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                </div>
```

Not all data cards I would like to crawl contain all of these fields, so defining them based on indexnumber does not work.

I would like to extract the values:

- Kampioenschaps clubmatches (value after the label class"pre" 'Type activiteit:')
- Jan Stuversdreef 4 (value after the label class"pre" 'Postcode:')

And so on, extracting the values for Adres, Plaats Inschrijven vanaf, etc.

I found the syntax for extracting Website and Email (//label[contains(.,'Website')]//..//..//a) But I am stuck figuring out how to get the 'none-a'values.

Any idears?

Comment: Please let me know if I understood correctly what you looking for?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you looking for, the following XPath will do what you looking for:

```xml
"//div[@class='row']//label[@class='post']"
```

Comment: This extracts all the info I want in one go. I was looking for a way to extract one value at a time. So I end up with one statement to extract the value of Adres, one statement to extract the value of Postcode etc.

Comment: something like this I guess?
<//div[@class='row']//label[@class='pre' contains(.,'Adres')]//label[@class='post']> (this does not work obviously BTW)